# Aurelia webpack referencing scripts that are not modules into IIFE

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, aurelia, iife

I have a script like this:

> myscript.js

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        root.sortable = factory(root.jQuery);
    }
}(this, function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#side-menu').metismenu();
}));
```

It has metismenu as dependency. Now if I put this script in the main.js as

`import './myscript`;

It throws that $().metismenu is nut a function.
So i added this to the script header:

```
import 'metismenu';
```

But it still throws the same error.
What is the properly way of handling such functions in aurelia?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with Aurelia. This is Webpack question. `metismenu` should be imported after jQuery in the same way that `jquery` is.